# WHERE clause, on joined table, with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have an `incidents` table which has a `1 to many` relationship with a few tables - mainly, for the context of this question, `people`.

Basically, one `incident` may have many `people` (involved).

At the moment, I'm retrieving the `incident` details - plus a concatenated comma-delimited string of people's IDs using this query:

```
SELECT
  i.`ID` AS `id`,
  i.`Author_ID` AS `author_id`,
  i.`Description` AS `description`,
  i.`Date` AS `date`,
  i.`Datetime_Created` AS `created`,
  p.`Title` AS `period`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip.`Person_ID` ORDER BY FIELD(ip.`Involvement`, 'V', 'P', 'W') ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS `people_ids`,
  ( SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `reports` r WHERE r.Incident_ID = i.ID ) AS `reports`,
  i.`Status` AS `status`
FROM `incidents` i
LEFT JOIN `reports` ir ON ir.Incident_ID = i.ID
LEFT JOIN `people` ip ON ip.Incident_ID = i.ID
LEFT JOIN `periods` p ON i.Period_ID = p.ID
WHERE 1 NOT IN ( SELECT Category_ID FROM `categories_link` WHERE `Incident_ID` = i.ID )
GROUP BY i.ID
ORDER BY i.`Date` DESC, p.`ID` DESC
```

This works fine, and produces data like:

[image: Data]

What I'm trying to do now is filter these reports so that **only incidents where one of the people involved is a student from a certain year group**.

This information can be found by joining their IDs to the `students` table. The `students` table contains their `ID` and a `Year_Group` field.

One of the complexities is that some of the IDs from the `people_involved` table **may not relate just to students** - they could be staff, parents or other members of our community.

I don't want to exclude reports which have **other people** involved, **as long as there is a student from a specific year group** involved too.

I've written a query which seems to partially work:

```
SELECT
  i.`ID` AS `id`,
  i.`Author_ID` AS `author_id`,
  i.`Description` AS `description`,
  i.`Date` AS `date`,
  i.`Datetime_Created` AS `created`,
  p.`Title` AS `period`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip.`Person_ID` ORDER BY FIELD(ip.`Involvement`, 'V', 'P', 'W') ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS `people_ids`,
  ( SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `reports` r WHERE r.Incident_ID = i.ID ) AS `reports`,
  i.`Status` AS `status`
FROM `incidents` i
LEFT JOIN `reports` ir ON ir.Incident_ID = i.ID
LEFT JOIN `people` ip ON ip.Incident_ID = i.ID
<< LEFT JOIN `student` stu ON ip.Person_ID = stu.db_id >>
LEFT JOIN `periods` p ON i.Period_ID = p.ID
WHERE 1 NOT IN ( SELECT Category_ID FROM `categories_link` WHERE `Incident_ID` = i.ID )
<< AND `stu`.`Year_Group` = 11 >>
GROUP BY i.ID
ORDER BY i.`Date` DESC, p.`ID` DESC
```

But I just can't imagine that a single simple `JOIN` would be sufficient for the task I'm trying to achieve.

I think a subquery might do it, but I don't know where to begin with that.

The code I would use to access this information (for *year 7 students*) without all of the necessary `incidents` data would be (I think):

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.`Incident_ID` )
FROM `people` p
LEFT JOIN `student` stu ON p.Person_ID = stu.db_id
WHERE stu.Year_Group = 7
```

How do I bundle that into this code?

Comment: I assume you need incidents where at least incident should have a student from specific age group included (in your case Year_Group 11).I have given an answer explaining conditions,check if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get incidents where students of only specific age group is included,use the following query.

```
   SELECT p.Incident_ID 
   FROM people p
   JOIN student stu ON p.Person_ID = stu.db_id
   WHERE stu.Year_Group = 11 
   group by p.Incident_ID
```

Your original query returns the incidents and the group of people involved ,So in your original query filter incidents by comparing with the above query written by me.This way you will get all incidents  where students from a specific year group involved plus other people also involved(if any).I think this will solve your problem.

```
 SELECT
      i.`ID` AS `id`,
      i.`Author_ID` AS `author_id`,
      i.`Description` AS `description`,
      i.`Date` AS `date`,
      i.`Datetime_Created` AS `created`,
      p.`Title` AS `period`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip.`Person_ID` ORDER BY FIELD(ip.`Involvement`, 'V', 'P', 'W') ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS `people_ids`,
      ( SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `reports` r WHERE r.Incident_ID = i.ID ) AS `reports`,
      i.`Status` AS `status`
    FROM `incidents` i
    LEFT JOIN `reports` ir ON ir.Incident_ID = i.ID
    LEFT JOIN `people` ip ON ip.Incident_ID = i.ID
    LEFT JOIN `periods` p ON i.Period_ID = p.ID
    WHERE 1 NOT IN ( SELECT Category_ID FROM `categories_link` WHERE `Incident_ID` = i.ID )
    and i.ID in //Here you will put the above query
    (
       SELECT p.Incident_ID 
       FROM people p
       JOIN student stu ON p.Person_ID = stu.db_id
       WHERE stu.Year_Group = 11 
       group by p.Incident_ID 
    )
    GROUP BY i.ID
    ORDER BY i.`Date` DESC, p.`ID` DESC
```

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want an OUTER JOIN on students.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 'student' stu on ip.Person_ID = stu.db_id
```

That will include all the incidents. Then, in the WHERE clause, add the filter

```
WHERE 1 NOT IN ( SELECT Category_ID FROM `categories_link` WHERE `Incident_ID` = i.ID ) AND `stu`.`Year_Group` = 7
```